# Unable to get the data from one Activity to Another Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I have created two Activities.

1. Main Activity.java(This is the activity that application launches with, user click on a button called "Show timer" which takes the user to the next activity)
2. displayTimer.java(This is the second activity which has a ListView, with data in each row. on item click users comes back to the main activity)

I'm trying to pass the string stored in that row to the main activity.

This is the main code from display timer activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_list_view);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customtimer_listview);
    customTimerAdapter = new CustomTimerAdapter(this, R.layout.row);
    BackGroundTask backGroundTask = new BackGroundTask(this);
    backGroundTask.execute("Get_info");
    registerForContextMenu(listView);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_entered);
            String timeRetrevied = textView.getText().toString();
            //System.out.println(timeRetrevied);
            Intent intentExtras = new Intent(displayTimer.this,MainActivity.class);
            intentExtras.putExtra("TIME_DATA",timeRetrevied);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intentExtras);
            //startActivityForResult(intentExtras,SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE,null);
            finish();

        }
    });

}
```

This is the code from the Main activity where i'm calling the method onActivityResult to get the data through intent from displaytimer. But i'm not able to get the data.    Dont know what i'm doing wrong. Any input with be fine.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            int setTimer = Integer.parseInt(data.getDataString());
            System.out.println(setTimer);
            seekbar.setProgress(setTimer * 60);
            updateTimer(setTimer);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not Ok");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("RequestCode failed");
}
```

}

Comment: String data = data.getExtra().getString("TIME_DATA")

Comment: `Intent intentExtras = new Intent(displayTimer.this,MainActivity.class);` That should be `Intent intentExtras = new Intent();`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
  data.getDataString()
```

use

```
data.getStringExtra("TIME_DATA")
```

getDataString returns the URI in the encoded String format, which is not what you require as you are not passing in the data.
As you are passing in the Sting text with ID=TIME_DATA, use the same ID to get the string back using the getStringExtra("TIME_DATA");

Comment: I tried data.getStringExtra("TIME_DATA")  but still nothing. It seems like onActivityResult method is not even running.